# How to set ERROR threshold for everything except my package

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I have configured logging via org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, console
log4j.logger.com.mypackage=INFO
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
// pattern, layout
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO
```

I use some 3-rd party code which use the logging by calling directly

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(name).callAppenders(...)
```

This call skip any level check and depend only on appender threshold.
I can't increase appender threshold because logs from my package also won't pass it.
I want INFO log level for my code and error for 3-rd party.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define 2 appenders, 1 for your stuff and another for the 3rd party stuff.  Then configure 2 logger that will ref. the appropriate appender with the right threshold.

Something like that:

```
<appender name="mystuff" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="../logs/mystuff.log" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />

    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="thridPartystuff" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="../logs/thirdParty.log" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />

    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.mystuf" additivity="true">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="mystuff" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.third.party.package">
    <level value="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="thridPartystuff" />
</logger>
```

Comment: actually the problem is with the console (you can't have two of them)

Comment: I never saw a restriction that does not let you define 2 appender with class org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender...!  But i don't see why you would define 2 appenders that log into the same source!  The way i see things, appenders are usefull to log different things in separate files to keep logs clean and organized.  just my 2c ;-)

Comment: sry but you just didn't understand the problem : you have to get rid of debug messages from 3-rd party libraries and keep yours.

Answer (score 1):

The solution which works (although I don't find it very nice) is similar to what have  Cygnusx1 proposed : define two console appenders with different thresholds and assign them accordingly :

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, console // receive error message on console from all packages
log4j.logger.com.problematic= , console2  // define another appender for the problematic package
log4j.additivity.com.problematic = false // don't propagate messages to root to avoid duplicates

log4j.appender.console2 = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console2.Threshold = ERROR
```